# Best Process Monitor In Ruby

Tags: ruby, process-monitoring

From experiences with process monitoring in Ruby, what do we recommend as the best process monitor. These are some of the features I'm interested in:

1. Efficient memory management without memory leaks
2. Monitor processes that are consuming a huge amount of RAM and automatically restart them
3. Optimum up time i.e automatically restart processes when they die off for some reason
4. Easy debugging i.e the process should still be able to log to a log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Eye](https://github.com/kostya/eye) gem now in one of our production apps and it's been running for the past 3 years. We haven't experienced any memory issues with it, although, we don't do heavy computational task with it.

Eye was inspired by [God](https://github.com/mojombo/god) and [Bluepill](https://github.com/bluepill-rb/bluepill). So far, I haven't experienced any memory leaks with Eye. The eye process itself is super light weight. Uses just about few kilobytes of memory and less than 1% of CPU.

You also have various features with eye such as easy debugs, memory monitoring for processes, cpu monitoring, nested process configuration, mask matching etc.

Eye is awesome, I do recommend it.